# Jquery Binding Events to Multiple Instances on a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding, textarea

I have a script working exactly the way I need, just now, I am not able to replicate it on a page - The jquery takes textarea boxes and edits them based on buttons being pressed, however I need each textarea box to have it's own set of buttons.  Here is my code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;" id="text">This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" id="button2" />

<br /><br />

<textarea style="width:500px; height: 150px;" id="text">This is some text</textarea>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me 2" id="button2" />
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$(function () {
$('#button').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#text');
    text.val(text.val() + "\n\nafter clicking");    
});
$('#button2').on('click', function () {
    var text = $('#text');
    text.val(text.val() + "\n\nafter clicking 2");    
});   });
```

**JS Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/42ssmu0t/

Thank you so much for helping me figure this out!

Comment: ID must be unique, check your HTML code

Comment: But then will I need to repeat the JS function for each textarea?

Comment: nop, just use **class** selector for that. For instance, add a class "my-button" to every input, then in jquery can do `$('.my-button').on('click', function () {`

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding ... if I make the class my-button, each button already has a class because there are multiple buttons - in my example, I have button1, button2 ... my textarea is txt, if I make another class in there like txt1, txt2, I am not sure how to add that into the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
 $(function () {
        $('*#button').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#text');
            text.val(text.val() + "\n\nafter clicking");
        });
        $('*#button2').on('click', function () {
            var text = $('#text');
            text.val(text.val() + "\n\nafter clicking 2");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated code on fiddle

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42ssmu0t/5/)

here is updated code :

```
$(function () {
$('*#button').on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).prevAll('#text').eq(0);
    text.val(text.val() + "\n\nafter clicking");    
});
$('*#button2').on('click', function () {
    var text = $(this).prevAll('#text').eq(0);
    text.val(text.val() + "\n\nafter clicking 2");    
});
});
```

Comment: Hi there - thank you so much - I copied your JS fiddle onto mine and added an additional function and it was not working - would you mind looking at my updated fiddle and see where I went wrong?  Here is one where I added your code into mine:  https://jsfiddle.net/yLotfgfh/